# Formula for sorting/ranking products by their user ratings

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, ranking, rating

I'm trying to get a decent sorting algorithm for my products database. Users can vote for their products with using scores from 0 to 5 (.5 scores are also possible like 2.5). My table structure currently looks like this:

```
[ProductID] [Title] ... [NumberOfVotes] [TotalPoints] [FinalScore]
```

Whenever a user votes, I'm calculating the finalscore using a very simple formula like
     (TotalPoints / NumberOfVotes) = FinalScore.

Then I sort the table on FinalScore and NumberOfVotes.

While this works, it's not exactly fair because a product which has only 1 vote of 5 stars can easily come in top rankings.

I'm not very good at statistics or algorithms to get a fair product ranking. 
I'm looking for a relatively easy-to-implement formula that's fairer than the method I'm using now.

How can this be done?

Comment: You might try and 'fudge' each new product with a bunch of average scores (around 2.5). This way, it will take several real votes to move the product rating, although it might give customers a bad impression about the product. Alternatively, don't include the product in your top rankings until it has at least N votes.

Answer (score 3):

I found a great post about this here that explains the various options, including thier pros and cons: [How Not To Sort By Average Rating](http://linkive.com/home/browser/MTU0MzY5/Comedy/How%20Not%20To%20Sort%20By%20Average%20Rating) but it seems that the correct solution is this...

> "Score = Lower bound of Wilson score
>   confidence interval for a Bernoulli
>   parameter"

seems daunting, but the post includes pseudocode and a clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median), which is often better a figure than raw average. In addition, you might consider not to give ratings for any item that has less than, say, five votes.